# Graph API post status not link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following simple PHP script to post to user wall:

```
$post =  array(
         'access_token' => '**************************',
         'name' => 'Click HERE to Play Game',
         'message' => '',
         'caption' => '3/19/2014',                 
         'description' => 'Click HERE to play the best game',
         'picture' => 'http://****.com/***.png' 
         );

$res = $facebook->api('12345/feed', 'POST', $post);
```

Everything shows well except there is a problem; The story links to the image attached to the story instead of the site URL.

I have configured the App Domain, Site URL, and Mobile URL fields but still the link won't show.

If I add the "link" field to the POST parameters, the post will be shown as a link not status update like this: "Michael shared a link" and the caption will not be shown although I overwrite it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way you share it (with or without `link`), the post will be shared as a link and not as a status update. The only way you can link to the game is to include the `link` parameter or add the link to the message.

When testing your code, the caption is published with and without using the `link` parameter.

---

EDIT:

I used the SDK to post the following update, with only the name, link, picture, caption and message fields filled in:

[image: FB Status Update]

The caption field works, and the description is automatically added from the page I linked to. It also says "shared a link via ." with a blank App name.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I'm talking specifically about the PHP SDK..The javascript for example doesn't cause this problem. If you remove the link parameter, it will be display without "shared a link" part. Although I define the caption, it's displayed as website link not the text i defined. Remember this all happens when posting through PHP don't know other SDK except javascript which works flawlessly

Comment: Yes, I know you are referring to the PHP SDK from your PHP code. I also tested this using the PHP SDK and got different results to you. The reason it doesn't say "shared a link" is because you don't share a link, you only post a image and some text. Have you tried using the Graph Explorer tool to try different combinations?

Comment: Strange enough there are apps that post daily on my wall like daily horoscope whcih post using PHP as well but without "shared a link" part and the story links to te canvas URL starting with apps.facebok.com. I thought that when i configure the site url and mobile url in app settings, it would detect automatically the link if i dont specify it. The caption problem is also very strange

Comment: Yes, the caption issue is a strange one. I've updated the answer with a real example of my testing.

Comment: the caption appears like your example if i view the story from my profile not on newsfeed because the thumbnail is small...when viewed from newsfeed, the thumbnail would be large and the caption would not appear...use the recommended thumb size of 1200x627 and you will notice the problem

Comment: the problem went away...it seems it was a bug :)